# counting integers in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of integers in a list.  I know I can do something like this to get a specific occurence:

```
List<ResultsViewModel> list = data.ToList<ResultsViewModel>();

            Response.Write(list[2].NoNotEncounterBarriersResult);
```

But how can I loop through and count number of instances of `list[i].NoNotEncounterBarriersResult = true`and return the result as an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Count`

```
var count = list.Count(item => item.NoNotEncounterBarriersResult)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx

Comment: First by 7 seconds! That's got to count for something ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx):

```
int count = list.Count(x => x.NoNotEncounterBarriersResult);
```

From the documentation:

> Returns a number that represents how many elements in the specified sequence satisfy a condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = list.Count(x => x.NoNotEncounterBarriersResult);
```

> [How to use Linq Count to get count?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36948/How-to-Use-LINQ-to-Get-a-Count-of-Duplicates-in-a)